# Cache Expiration event asp.net enterprise library

Tags: asp.net

I wanted to know if there is any event which occurs each time a cache item is about too get expired or any event which is raised when a cache item is getting expired.I am using enterprise library in asp.net for caching.I want to store some data in my database when a cache is about to get expired instead of calling a function or invoking an event myself I was thinking of using the already managed cache library event which is being used to flush or dispose cache items.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're using the Caching Application Block then you specify a callback delegate when you add items to the cache.

> Receiving notification of an item's removal from the cache requires that you specify the class implementing ICacheItemRefreshAction on the call to the Add method

You need to supply a class implementing `ICacheItemRefreshAction`:

```
[Serializable]
public class ProductCacheRefreshAction : ICacheItemRefreshAction
{
  public void Refresh(string key, object expiredValue, CacheItemRemovedReason removalReason)
  {
    // Item has been removed from cache. Perform desired actions here, based on
    // the removal reason (for example, refresh the cache with the item).
  }
}
```

As you can see, when an item is removed, this `Refresh()` method is called with the key *and* the object that's being removed. You just need to cast the `expiredObject` parameter to the correct type and arrange to have it stored to the database.

As documented here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff664621(v=PandP.50).aspx

Comment: Would this give me the old cache object as well? i.e my basic requirement is to save the old cached data after the cached item has expired.

Comment: Another quick question does the refresh function internally work on multithreading ?